# TextInputAction.done not showing "Done" button in iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

**Code:**

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
)
```

---

**Current screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Expected screenshot:**

[image]